# Borrowing error when there is no visible borrow

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm still new to rust, so I'm not sure why there is an error here.

```
        Ok(Value::Object(m)) => 
            ...
            let colours: Vec<&'static CardColour>;
            //Note: type annotation requires that `m` is borrowed for `'static`
            ...

            let colour_res: Result<Vec<&CardColour>, _> =
                if let Some(Value::Array(v)) = m.get("cardid") {
                    /*
                    Error here:
                    `m` does not live long enough
                    borrowed value does not live long enough
                    */
                    v
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|v|{
                        match v {
                            Value::String(s) => {
                                if let Some(cc) = CardColour::from_name(s.as_str()){
                                    Ok(cc.clone())
                                } else {
                                    Err(())
                                }
                            },
                            _ => Err(())
                        }
                    })
                    .collect()
                } else {
                    Err(())
                };

            if let Ok(cc) = colour_res {
                colours = cc
            } else {
                return Err(String::from("Missing or invalid colours"));
            };
            ...
            //Note: `m` dropped here while still borrowed
            //(End of function)
```

As near as I can tell, `m` stops being used once `colour_res` is assigned.

`CardColour::from_name` is defined as follows

```
impl CardColour{
    fn from_name (s: &str) -> Option<&CardColour>{
        card_colours.get(s.to_lowercase().as_str()).cloned()
    }
}
```

So, by my reckoning, the value extracted from `m` should now be finished with and it should no longer be missing.

Am I missing something obvious here? Why is `m` "still borrowed" at the end of the function even though the values extracted have been used and finsished with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something obvious here? Why is m "still borrowed" at the end of the function even though the values extracted have been used and finsished with?

The problem is this:

```rust
fn from_name (s: &str) -> Option<&CardColour>
```

Because you don't specify lifetimes, Rust's [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) rules simply consider that the output lifetime is the same as the input:

> If there is exactly one lifetime used in the parameters (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

Therefore the `&CardColour` is considered to keep the `&str` borrow alive, and since that comes from `m` it requires the borrow on `m`.

This is valid because `'static` is a superset of all lifetimes, and thus a `'static` lifetime can be "cast" to any other with no error.

The solution is to explicitly specify that the output lifetime is `'static`.

Trivial demo:

```rust
fn foo(_: &str) -> &u8 {
    &1
}

fn main() {
    let v = foo(&String::new());
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

fixed version:

```rust
struct Foo;
fn foo(_: &str) -> &'static u8 {
    &1
}

fn main() {
    let v = foo(&String::new());
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

Comment: I see. That's something I didn't see (or possibly overlooked) in the docs and references I was using. I'll have to read over that section. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit unintuitive, the trick is to remember that Rust does not do global inference, functions are a hard boundary, so when a function is defined as `fn (&T) -> &U` *that is all the caller gets to know*, as far as the type system is concerned. Therefore the only thing the output lifetime can be based on is the input lifetime, those are the only lifetimes available. Technically `'static` is also "available" but making output lifetimes static by default would be completely broken and would work in very few cases, so it's not really an option.